# Layout for html site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a site with HTML, CSS, JS (And of course Jquery), VueJS and Bootstrap. I'm wondering if there is a way to make some sort of 'layout' file that can be reused over and over? I don't want to copy paste all the HTML for my top bar every time I make a new page or have to go through every page and update that code. I've tried using the  tag with javascript to put different HTML files (Content) inside of a 'layout' file but I've had trouble with formatting. Should I continue down that route? Is there another easier way?

It would be nice if there was a way to do it similar to blazor where you can just write some HTML and then do an @Body.

Comment: does [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_1) answers your question ?

Comment: You can use snippets depending on your editor. Like vscode allows you to make snippets that can be triggered with !HTML

Comment: Vue should allow you to create a base template that is used on all pages: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/02/24/extending-vuejs-components-templates/#creating-a-base-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a SPA through the use of Jquery. The index.html file contains my navbar and then the content is put into a "content" div which is populated by separate page.html files. All you have to do is make a page.html file and then go to site.com/#page and the router handles everything else. This code also needs to be run on page load..

```js
$(window).on("hashchange", function ()
 {     
   var page = window.location.hash;     
   console.log(page.substring(1));   
  
   $.get(page.substring(1) + ".html", function (pageContent) {       
   $("#content").html(pageContent);     
   });  
});
```